# How to use condition base on url in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs framework,Right now i want if url containing  "?id=pinned" then different text should display,How can i do this ? Here is my current code in [slug.js]

```
return(
        if(url containing pinned)
        {
            <div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Pinned</h3></div>
        }
        else
        {
         <div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Newest</h3></div>
        }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like you're using Next.js, you can use Next.js API to do this

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { id } = router.query
  const isPinned = id === 'pinned'
  
  if (isPinned) {
     return (<div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Pinned</h3></div>)
  } else {
     return (<div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Newest</h3></div>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const {query} = useRouter()
  const isPinned = query.id === 'pinned'
  return (<div id="neww" className="neww">
           <h3>{isPinned ? 'Pinned': 'Newest'}</h3>
         </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ignore if else, you should try the ternary operator

```
return(
        <div id="neww" className="neww">
          <h3> 
            {(url.includes('pinned') ? "Pinned":"Newest" }                         
          </h3>
       </div>
)
```

Comment: i am getting error "url is not defined"

Comment: is URL  variable ? or are you referring document.URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query from router

Example

```
const router = useRouter();
const {id} = router.query;


return(
        if(id === "pinned")
        {
            <div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Pinned</h3></div>
        }
        else
        {
         <div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Newest</h3></div>
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

  const router = useRouter();
  const id = router.query["id"];
  return(
        if(id === "pinned")
        {
            <div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Pinned</h3></div>
        }
        else
        {
         <div id="neww" className="neww"><h3>Newest</h3></div>
        }
)
```